# Quando devo usar o ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Além do `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout`, dentre outros já existentes, que suprem bastante as necessidades relacionadas a *layout*, o Google anunciou no [Google I/O 2016](https://events.google.com/io2016/)  o [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

- Observando que tem muita semelhança com `RelativeLayout`, qual seria a diferença entre os dois?
- Quando devo usar o `ConstraintLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

Quando você precisar de `layouts` mais complexos e que irão precisar de uma hierarquia mais precisa.

O `ConstraintLayout` foi criado, de acordo com a [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), para criar telas com uma hierarquia mais precisa, sem precisar aninhar as `views`. Ou seja, sempre que tu for fazer um layout relativamente complexo e que precise de um alinhamento preciso, tu tem que usar `ConstraintLayout`. O objetivo desta view é justamente isso, permitir que os desenvolvedores possam otimizar as hierarquias das suas telas.

> Vantagens

- Otimizado para hierarquias de exibição
- Você não terá problemas se o estado de visibilidade da sua **view** for `GONE`, o alinhamento funcionará mesmo assim e você não vai mais se preocupar com layouts quebrados.
- Editor completamente amigável
- Fácil de usar e feito para desenhar telas responsivas

> Desvantagens

- O layout editor vai simplesmente mover suas views sem motivo algum, isso deve ser causado quando tentamos mover uma view e acabamos clicando em outra.
- Performance. A performance em que as views são criadas é um pouco inferior se comparar ao `RelativeLayout` ou `LinearLayout`.
- O principal problema é o **editor**. Com o passar do tempo, tu vai perceber que o editor faz coisas inesperar, então tu vai acabar preferindo por criar teus layouts manualmente. Eu prefiro. É melhor e um pouco mais rápido.